# Explain this JS shorthand: `var myVar = i === 0`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax

I am learning React with http://buildwithreact.com/tutorial/state

There is a code snippet that contains a piece of JS code I have never encountered before - **line 5** (with a comment included). I think it is a shorthand. What does it express?

```
var BoardSwitcher = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var boards = [];
    for (var ii = 0; ii < this.props.numBoards; ii++) {
      var isSelected = ii === 0;  // WHAT DOES THIS MEAN ???
      boards.push(
        <Board index={ii} selected={isSelected} key={ii} />
      );
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="boards">{boards}</div>
        <button>Toggle</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Its a boolean set to true only when `ii` is `0` (first iteration of the loop)

Comment: If `i` equals `0` it will set the `myVar` to `true`, else `myVar` will be `false`

Comment: @Kaiido Can You rewrite it using normal JS syntax so I can fully understand that pls?

Comment: It's not shorthand, really. It is declaring a variable called `isSelected`. And the initial value of that variable is the result of the expression `i===0`. Nothing is weird here at all. Evaluate the expression. It will be  `true` or `false`. Then that is the initial value of the variable. Were you confused by the `===`?

Comment: @LGSon OK, thx very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`===` is an operator that tests equality without autocasting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness), and returns a boolean value; `true` if the two values are equal and of the same type, `false` otherwise. This boolean value is then assigned to the variable `isSelected`.

[You can interactively try it](https://repl.it/@phihag/jseq) to see what happens:

```
> var ii = 0;
> var isSelected = ii === 0;
> console.log(isSelected);
true
> var ii = 1;
> var isSelected = ii === 0;
> console.log(isSelected);
false
```

Comment: So, for newbies it should be like `var isSelected = (ii === 0)`, right?

Comment: @Penny Dreadful. Precisely! Since [`the operator precedence of =` is way down](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), the parentheses are usually left out.